# Laravel - API Versioning: Use latest controller if controller not found in vX directory

Tags: laravel, api, versioning, api-design

I'm working on a v2 of my Laravel API and trying to find a strategy to prevent as much new code as possible.

So what I thought about is this: Let's say the API has 6 versions. Now a breaking change happens in the `UserController`. The project structure looks like this:

```
- Controllers
--- V1
------ CarController
------ UserController
------ ...
--- V2
--- ...
--- V3
------ CarController
------ ...
--- ...
--- V7
------ UserController
```

So the endpoint `/v7/users` uses the UserController in V7 directory. But let's say `/v7/cars` gets called. With manual handling of the `routes/api.php` file the API would return a `404`.

But wouldn't be it great, that if `/v7/cars` gets called, the `CarController` in V3 would be used automatically? Am I short-sighted here? If not, is this possible? For example by using a middleware?

A big advantage of this solution would be that all clients would only have to change the version once in the BASE_URL of the API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Simply make the routes use the appropriate action.

```php
Route::get('api/v3/cars', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V3\CarsController::class, 'index']);
                ^^                                  ^^
Route::get('api/v7/cars', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V3\CarsController::class, 'index']);
                ^^                                  ^^
```

2. Create a `V7/CarsContrller`, but use the `__call` magic method to handle the logic

```
Route::get('api/v3/cars', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V3\CarsController::class, 'index']);
                ^^                                  ^^
Route::get('api/v7/cars', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V7\CarsController::class, 'index']);
                ^^                                  ^^
```

2.1. To redirect:

```
// V7/CarsController
class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect all calls to v7/cars to their equivalent in v3/cars
     *
     * @var $method        string
     * @var $parameters    array
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        return redirect()->action([
            \App\Http\Controllers\Api\V3\CarsController::class,
            $method,
            ...$parameters
        ]);
    }
}
```

2.1. Or to simply do the same:

```php
// V7/CarsController
class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Use v3 api behind the scenes
     *
     * @var $method        string
     * @var $parameters    array
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        return app(\App\Http\Controllers\Api\V3\CarsController::class)->{$method}(...$parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with this, I also need a CarController in v7 folder or need to add/change code in api.php. I thought about a solution where I only define all the endpoints in the api.php file and a middleware(?) handles which Controller should be used.

Comment: The logic has to live somewhere. Of course, you can try to do it in a middleware too. Do it in a way that makes sense to you